# HttpClient GetStringAsync returns 301, but browsers are able to navigate to correct address

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, http-status-code-301

I thought that `HttpClient` should be able to handle `301` error code, and redirect to the correct address. However with the following address (https://www.npr.org/templates/rss/podcast.php?id=510298), it throws exception. The browsers are able to handle it properly though. Just like to understand if there is a way out or am I missing something.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var s = await client
    .GetStringAsync("https://www.npr.org/templates/rss/podcast.php?id=510298");
```

throws

```
Test1 [0:00.779] Failed: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Response 
status code does not indicate success: 301 (Moved Permanently).
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Response status code does not 
indicate success: 301 (Moved Permanently).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetStringAsyncCore(Task`1 getTask)
   at XUnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.Test1() in 
   C:\Users\res\source\repos\test\XUnitTestProject1\UnitTest1.cs:line 13
```

Comment: when you are following a url and get a 301 error, then you have to handle the error and make a new call, this is what a browser is doing behind the scence. the HTTP client can't do that for you because it doesn't know what you want to do about the error, ie do you want to update the location you have the url saved so that the next call goes directly to the new url,  do you want to follow the link to the new address, do you want to call a different url instead, do you want to fail the operation. how you handle the exception is entirely upto you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found the reason. Generally `HttpClient` would handle the redirects properly, but it does not handle redirects if it is from `https -> http`. Which is the case here. I was stumped by the response of the chrome browser, the displayed redirected url in chrome started with https (**https**://www.npr.org/rss/podcast.php?id=510298), but the actual redirect was to **http**://www.npr.org/rss/podcast.php?id=510298

There is an explanation at https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/21446#issuecomment-298323133